# GitKraken asking for GitHub credentials despite ssh key upload

Tags: gitkraken

In preferences→Integrations→GitHub I uploaded a GitKraken SSH key to GitHub. However, after pressing “Pull” GitKraken still asks me to log in, which does not work. The login dialog pops up again and again.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a closed port at our firewall was the problem. I wonder if GitKraken can’t tell the difference between that and a failed authentication at GitHub. And if so, maybe it should first test the SSH port with other means, e.g. authenticating somewhere it knows it can.